# How to fetch Particular User Page View from site using Google Analytics Based on website userId in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-analytics, report

I have checked google analytics documentation but that fetch data based on google analytics userId

I want to fetch **particular Page view** data based on website userId

Comment: Hello Ankit, are you able to provide code or any examples of what you've tried so far so that someone can better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User Activity API allows a Google Analytics property owner to retrieve all analytics measurement **data associated with a single user**. Specifically, the API retrieves all of the measurement data associated with a particular **User ID** or Client ID.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting

**PageviewData**
This field contains all the details about the visitor and the page that was visited.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search#PageviewData

Comment: Ok Where we are setting the ‘userId’ field and its value as ‘147’. This 147 is the ID within our application like a primary key that is used to individually identify an user. and also I wants  count of  particular page visited

Comment: Pass it as custom dimension too (user scope) and get this with API.

Comment: Can you please provide how can I do using API with some code example in java ?